# XMLHttpRequestPost сервер шлет что-то нечитаемое

Tags: ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

Есть код

```js
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let formData = $(this).serializeArray();
      console.log('22 string', formData);
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = '';
      xhr.open('POST', 'new 1.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application / json');
      xhr.onload = function(response) {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        if (xhr.readyState = 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          console.log('отклик', xhr.response);
          console.log('текст отклика', xhr.responseText);
        } else {
          alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
        };
      };
      xhr.send(formData); //пробовал encodeURIComponent(formData) 
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
  <input name="address" type="text" value="" />
  <input name="email" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить в PDF">
</form>
```

в результате в консоли Chrome:

```
22 string (2) [{…}, {…}]0: 
{name: "address", value: "da"}1: 
{name:  "email", value: "net"}
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
[Violation] 'submit' handler took 1767ms
4
200
отклик 
текст отклика 
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/val.loc/new%201.php".
```

смотрю Headers: в Response Headers Content-Length: 0
смотрю Form Data:[object Object],[object Object]: 
понимаю что ответ сервера на обращение положительный, но шлет нечто нечитаемое или пустое? Почему и как это исправить?
Обработчик на стороне сервера:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["address"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) ) {
$result = array(// Формируем массив для JSON ответа
    'address' => $_POST["address"],
    'email' => $_POST["email"]
);
// Переводим массив в JSON
echo json_encode($result); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Зачем затираете значения *Content-Type* передавая его дважды?

   ```
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application / json');
   ```
2. `if (xhr.readyState = 4 && xhr.status == 200) {...` Здесь вы затираете ответ, вместо xhr.readyState = 4 для проверки пишите `xhr.readyState == 4`.
3. Вынести проверки в скобки:

   ```
   if ( (xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200) ) {
     //...
   ```

Comment: из консоли Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 application / json заголовки добавляются, по консоли все нормально 4 - запрос выполнен. 200 - ответ от сервера пришел...закавыка где не понимаю

Comment: @Эйссер, вы исправили код, где я говорил? Ответ от сервера будет нормальным. "Закавыка" с его дальнейшей обработкой в JS.

Comment: @Эйссер, и потом, *Content-Type* пишется, как *'application/json'* - без пробелов.

Comment: да исправил, попробовал: результат тот же (консоль не обманешь) Понимаю что JS не может обработать!!!Он его не видит, или сервер отдает json ответ как-то криво, не согласовано с браузером))))

Comment: @Эйссер, "не верю" :) © Станиславский. Удалите кэш и перезагрузите страницу несколько раз через *Ctrl + R*. 1) Посмотрите исходный код скрипта именно в браузере и пришлите его скриншот. 2) Откройте панель разработчика, перейдите на вкладку *Network* и отфильтруйте запросы по параметру *XHR*, посмотрите, что присылает сервер. Выделите нужный запрос и откройте уже в запросе вкладку *Response*.

Comment: работаю через Denwer, Chrome в гостевом режиме (шоб не кэшиться) вкладка Response в обработчике new 1.php пусто: "this request no response data available - загадка природы, скриншот не вижу как здесь файлы прикладываются

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200329/view-ajax-response-content-in-chrome-developer-tools 2) В php-файле перед выводом echo json_encode($result); добавить на всяк случай *header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');* 3) По прикреплению https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8135/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-stack-overwlow-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE

Comment: @Kosmos...в итоге заработало, но какой-то бермудский треугольник: на сервере исполнил манипуляции с json_decode, через var_dump вывелся массив...все убрал...запустился и response пришел, правда с null элементами...но пришел!? Правда я еще FireFox Debugger подключил...загадка)))????

Comment: @Эйссер, не знаю, вы еще скриншот не прислали :)